# Performwithsegue and programatically switching views - Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, segue, viewcontroller

I am having a problem, I want to change to another viewcontroller when a timer expires and this works with this code:

```
- (IBAction)Akkoord:(id)sender {
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Innameformulier"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
    [self performseguewithidentifier:@"nextcontroller"]
}
```

But when I use this, my variables in my `prepareforsegue` method are not passing. How can I do this? I already tried `[self performseguewithidentifier]` but this is not working.

my preparforsegue code is:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    Innameformulier *IForm = [segue destinationViewController];
    IForm.SignatureTransport = _drawImage.image;
    IForm.KlantnaamInname = _Klantnaamtransport;
}
```

How can I call this function to happen on the timer?

Comment: If the current view controller is from the storyboard then you don't need to do this. Just do `perform segue`. Show the storyboard and the prepare for segue code. Also, what you are doing here is creating a brand new storyboard not using the one you are already in. Also, you don't need to create the VC the storyboard does that for you.

Comment: The prepareforsegue code is: - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    Form *IForm = [segue destinationViewController];
    IForm.SignatureTransport = _drawImage.image;

Comment: What I want is to call this from another method, so that it performs when the timer expires

Comment: OK, which is the bit that isn't working? Is it not getting the image? You should edit your question to put the code in. It's easier to read :D

Comment: Can you show more code. It's hard to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have two viewcontrollers. I want to go to the secondviewcontroller when the timer expires, and this works with the code in my question! But the part that is'nt working is passing the variables in the prepareforsegue method. Is there some code to call the function?

Comment: OK, but how are you presenting the second view controller. Please show that code.

Comment: The presenting code is in the question above, that code works perfectly, the 2nd viewcontroller shows up, but the variables are not passed

Comment: It doesn't work "perfectly" if something isn't working. :P How are you triggering this code though? How are you actually making it appear. This is not what the prepareForSegue method does. What is the bit that is actually calling the transition/segue? That's the code I'm interested in. The bit that has the code that you posted in the initial question.

Comment: At the moment I am triggering it from a buttonaction, when I press the button I want the other viewcontroller to appear. I know this works with segues in my storyboard but I want to do it programmatically. This works fine, the viewcontroller shows up. But my variables are not passed. With a storyboard-segue, I can do this with the Prepareforsegue method, but this does'nt work. So my question is: Is there a way to call the Prepareforsegue button from that same action. So that it triggers without a storyboard-segue

Comment: OK, please show all the buttonAction code. Segues work and you can pass variable across them. Something you are doing is not correct. The only way to know what it is is to see your code. But you are not posting the code so that we can see and help.

Comment: Yes, the way to perform a segue is to use `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"someIdentifier"];` but please show your code first so I can see what is happening.

Comment: Also, if this is not working... have you given the segue an identifier? Click on the segue arrow and look in the attributes inspector. It should have an "Identifier" in there with some text. This is the text you use for the `performSegueWithIdentifier` code.

Comment: I am showing up the secondviewcontroller programatically so I have no actual segue, or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, you need a segue. CTRL-drag from the first view controller to the second view controller. Then give the segue an identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, what you are doing here is bypassing the segue completely. You need to do something like this...

```
- (IBAction)Akkoord:(id)sender {
    [self performseguewithidentifier:@"nextcontroller"]
}
```

This is all you need to do. The segue will then create the nextController for you and then the code inside `prepareForSegue` will pass the variables across.

If you want it on a timer then you just need to set up a timer and when it expires you can run...

```
[self performseguewithidentifier:@"nextcontroller"]
```

As long as you have a segue with this identifier then it will work anywhere. Ever after a timer.

Comment: Thank you very much Fogmeister! It worked. I was a little confused

Comment: No worries :D Glad you got it working. It can be a little confusing going between IB and code.

Answer (score 1):

In `Interface Builder`, select the View Controller from which you want to fire a segue, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-drag from it to the destination View Controller and create a segue.

Select the segue, open the Attributes Inspector and create an Identifier for it.

Go back to your `View Controller Class` that fires the segue and if you don't already have it commented, add the method `prepareForSegue:`

In your `prepareForSegue:` method you should have something like the following:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"XXXX"]) {

        DestinationVC *dVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        dVC.attribute1 = self.anAttribute;
        dVC.attribute2 = self.anotherAttribute;
   }
}
```

And now you can fire the segue by calling `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"XXXX"]`.

Note: you can also fire an action segue from an `UIControl` subclass like `UIButton`

[image]